# Сканер штрих-кода под .Net 2.0

Tags: c#

Раньше на Delphi использовал для работы со сканером ШК компонент BComPort или WinAPI (CreateFile). Теперь необходимо встроить в прогу на C# такое-же. Есть у кого-то готовый класс (библиотека) под DOT.NET 2.0?

Answer (score 1):

Есть библиотека POS for .NET

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Читал в сети. Принял решение: пишу "небезопасный код" (в терминологии .Net), а далее, как говорится, по расписанию...

Answer (score 1):

Есть еще стандартный .NET'овский [SerialPort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx).

UPDATED: Оп, сорри, под 2.0 нету :(